# unifying model for 'static' / 'historical' /streaming data in F#

Tags: f#, metaprogramming, quotations

An API I use exposes data with different characteristics :

- 'Static' reference data, that is you ask for them, get one value which supposedly does not change
- 'historical' values, where you can query for a date range
- 'subscription' values, where you register yourself for receiving updates

From a semantic point of view, though, those fields are one and the same, and only the consumption mode differs. Reference  data can be viewed as a constant function yielding the same result through time. Historical data is just streaming data that happened in the past.

I am trying to find a unifying model against which to program all the semantic of my queries, and distinguish it from its consumption mode.

That mean, the same quotation could evaluated in a "real-time" way which would turn fields into their appropriate IObservable form (when available), or in 'historical' way, which takes a 'clock' as an argument and yield values when ticked, or a 'reference' way, which just yield 1 value (still decorated by the historical date at which the query is ran..)

I am not sure which programming tools in F# would be the most natural fit for that purpose, but I am thinking of quotation, which I never really used.
Would it be well suited for such a task ?

Answer (score 0):

you said it yourself: just go with IObservable

- your static case is just OnNext with 1 value
- in your historical case you OnNext for each value in your query (at once when a observer is registered)
- and the subscription case is just the ordinary IObservable pattern - you don't need something like quotations for this.

Comment: So that all those fields would be of type : IClock -> IObservable<'T> ?

Comment: yes why not - but I don't think you really need the IClock thing at first if you make it `IObservable<DateTime*'T>` or if you have some way to extract the times from `'T` - if you need the finegrained IClock-ticks you can seperatly

Comment: I probably need the independent clocks as the many fields would be as many data sources, which, if I want to play back, would need some form of synchronization. I imagined that had to go through a common shared stateful variable representing the time

Answer (score 0):

I have done something very similar (not the static case, but the streaming and historical case), and `IObservable` is definitely the right tool for the job. In reality, `IEnumerable` and `IObservable` are dual and most things you can write for one you can also write for the other. However, a push based model (`IObservable`) is more flexible, and the operators you get as part of `Rx` are more complete and appropriate than those as part of regular `IEnumerable` LINQ.

Using quotations just means you need to build the above from scratch.

You'll find the following useful:

- `Observable.Return(value)` for a single static value
- `list.ToObservable()` for turning a historical enumerable to an observable
- Direct `IObservable` for streaming values into IObservable

Also note that you can use virtual schedulers for ticking the observable if this helps (most of the above accept a scheduler). I imagine this is what you want for the historical case.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Rx-Workshop/Rx-Workshop-Schedulers